# Creating XML in T-SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, xml-namespaces

I have a little trouble. How I can make a root node for XML file in T-SQL like this?

```
<Root xmlns="http://www.bla-bla.org" 
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

</Root>
```

This format looks like mix elements and namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This format looks like mix Elements and namespaces

No, you are defining a default namespace and two namespaces with the prefixes `xs:` and `xsi:`:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.bla-bla.org'
                  ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xs
                  ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
SELECT 'blah' AS [@SomeAttribute]
      ,'dummy' AS SomeNode
FOR XML PATH('SomeElement'),ROOT('root');
```

The result

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.bla-bla.org">
  <SomeElement SomeAttribute="blah">
    <SomeNode>dummy</SomeNode>
  </SomeElement>
</root>
```

Comment: @Andrew_Exp, Hi, It is very kind of you to say *thanks*, but it would be even kinder to tick the acceptance check. Once you've crossed the 15 rep points border yourself, your are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. Happy Coding!